# deciphering WebResponse string into list of arrays

Tags: c#, winforms, data-transfer, encryption

There is a PHP script which is located on the website. I also have a C# winforms program which sends POST messages using WebRequest/WebResponse approach.

This PHP script connects to mysql database, grabs some data and sends it back to WinForms app. The data has following format:

> John, 32, may
>
> Peter, 24, June
>
> etc..

All this text is sent as a single string. **What's the best approach to decipher this string into a list of strings[] ?**

Right now I'm using a self-made approach. PHP script does the following:

- first we separate each word with ","
- then we separate each line with "|"

When I receive the message I divide it into a list using "|" letter

```
List<string> names = input.Split('|').ToList<string>();
```

then I divide each string inside the list:

```
List<string[]> namestwo = new List<string[]>();
foreach (string str in names)
{
string[] sep = str.Split(',').ToArray();
namestwo.Add(sep);
}
```

I suppose that there is a better way to do it..

Comment: As your data doesn't contain any actual commas (',') or pipes ('|') this is a perfectly acceptable approach.

Comment: well, actually it doesn't contain commas in my example.. but in real life situation I don't exclude the possibility that someone will be using commas inside names.. i.e. "nick,nam|e".. that's when it becomes comlicated (whole line will look like this: "nick,nam|e,56,August|someone,15,may")

Answer (score 0):

Your general approach is just fine.  Using delimiters when sending data like this is quite common.  Obviously you'll need to make sure that your data either won't ever have any commas (',') or pipes ('|') in it, or that you escape those characters properly and then handle it properly when parsing.  If you find yourself having a lot of commas or pipes you can consider using other delimiters (tabs are a nice option because you can usually replace all tabs in the data with a few spaces instead of escaping them).

You can clean up the code a bit if you wanted to.  Something like this looks nicer to me, but it'll be fundamentally doing the same thing:

```
var result = input.Split('|')
             .Select(line => line.Split(',').ToList()).ToList();
```